# Codeigniter - is it risky to modify the cart $product_name_rules to accept any character?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using the Cart Class in CI, and my product names contain lots of "dangerous" characters, such as apostrophe, brackets, semicolon, ampersands, and many non latin characters.

The Cart Class limits the allowed characters like so:

```
var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9'; // alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, colons or periods
```

I know I can extend the Cart Class and override this limitation with something like this in a MY_Cart Class:

```
$this->product_name_rules = '\d\D';
```

But this makes me wonder - perhaps the CI people had a reason for limiting the product names. Maybe by removing the limitation I'm opening a backdoor to hackers.

Obviously, when I add items from the cart to my database, I use Active Records and query binding, which should (to my best understanding) provide a sufficient defense against sql injections and the like.

So what was the idea behind limiting the characters in the first place?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the name of the products? For example you have urlencode, although it's used to encode strings so you can pass them on the url I think that maybe this does the job. Here check the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO! Well, let me say: "None that I could see":

Although codeigniter seemed to throw some errors when I modified regex of the cart core directly. So I just tweaked by leaving what's there and just adding /d/D at the end like this:

```
var $product_name_rules = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9\d\D'; // alpha-numeric, dashes, underscores, colons or periods
```

---

To not mess with original classes for reasons you might not know, try to extend the class

You could find guides here:

> http://ponderwell.net/2010/07/codeigniter-extending-the-cart-class-for-robust-product-names/

Create a file in application/libraries and call it "MY_cart.php". In that file, paste the following code:

```
< ?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Cart extends CI_Cart {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->product_name_rules = '\d\D';
    }
}
```

Comment: I just fixed an error in the regex. This should work fine now.

Comment: Thanx for reinforcing what I initially thought. I couldn't find any reason why it should be dangerous, but out of respect to the CI developers, I wanted to know for sure :-)

Comment: My product names/titles used brackets () and where rejected by the cart class regex. I made the above modifications and it worked pretty well. Really, I've not observed any strange behaviour or security risk since then. Maybe if anyone else does, they'd let us know. At the moment, I've not seen one person who has seen a major bug by allowing all characters in product titles. Not all products can be named the same way. Mine needed the brackets and a few other characters. You could consider your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth getting to know the CI cart library. Because then when you make your own cart, it will make you feel really good about yourself. :-) Seriously though, everyone who tries the CI cart runs into this issue and there are many posts about it. So yes you can modify it so you can use different characters in the names - but i would seriously urge you to make your own cart as soon as possible.

what does a shopping cart really need from the product page? It needs the ID of the product, and the Qty. thats it - everything else should come directly from your product table.

do not set up your app so that there is a price on a product page, and then you take that price and send it to the cart. someone could easily modify the form and send a lower price to the cart.

so verify the product id - then get the product price DIRECTLY from the product table. and thats easy because you just did it to show the product. you can also get the product name that way and - hey suddenly you dont have to worry at all about dangerous characters, and you know that the price will be accurate.

---

and Steward has the excellent answer for working with ci cart lib, and the blog post he links to steps through the issues. you can also copy parts of the cart lib and put them in MY_cart, its a good way to see how it works and you can do simple mods.

Comment: Thanx for the advice. I'll think about creating my own cart, but up until now, the CI cart does a pretty good job for me. The character limitation was the only issue I ran into so far, and I already solved it by extending the cart class. I was just wondering if that solution is dangerous in any way. And I have to grab the price from the page, because I'm using a discount system that relies on the user state (member or not, referred by an affiliate or not), so the price varies from the set price in the db.

Comment: yeah i work with a version where the discount is applied post product database. total pain but i learned some good lessons. CI cart is good for getting up and running, i used it for months, just some encouragement to take next step when you need to build out more features etc.